# How to say "Sheriff" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I assumed with my very limited knowledge it would be シェリフ, however when I put it into a sentence with Google Translate, シェリフ instead was represented as 保安官, and pronounced ホアンカン rather than シェリフ. So now I want to confirm what the proper way to say/write "Sheriff" is. I think perhaps Google Translate pronouncing it ホアンカン could simply be it misreading Kanji, and I do not know enough about Kanji to be sure so I want to ask...

What is the proper way to pronounce/write "Sheriff" and would it change depending on if I'm using it in a sentence, or other specific context?

Comment: It may help if you define what the function of a Sheriff is. There may be no direct equivalent. As a UK native when someone says sherriff I think of Robin Hood. I'm guessing you're referring to some sort of US police officer but I don't know what nuances that suggests to a US native.

Comment: Context is king. The English term _sheriff_ has many meanings.  What meaning are you trying to translate, and in what context?  Also, Google Translate is _*terrible*_ at translating single words.  **Never** use Google Translate as an authoritative source.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Absolutely! The meaning I am trying to translate is the title of sheriff in an "old west" setting. The context is I have a character who is a sheriff, and will simply be referred to as Sheriff throughout the story.

Comment: @user3856370 Oh interesting! Actually the context goes further back than it's modern meaning, I actually forgot here in the US we _still_ have modern day "sheriff" police officers, haha. I'm referring to like an old west cowboy sheriff, I have a character in an old west setting who is a sheriff and will simply be referred to as "Sheriff".

Comment: To be pedantic, in the USA, the title of "sheriff" is strictly determined by jurisdiction. A sheriff's jurisdiction is to enforce laws passed by "county" legislatures. The USA is divided into States. And a State is divided into "counties" (except Louisiana where "counties" are called "parishes" for historical reasons). In summary, Japan doesn't have legal jurisdictions at a "county" or "parish" level, so no "sheriff".

Comment: Why would you assume 保安官 should be pronounced as シェリフ?

Comment: @istrasci Because Google Translate is unhelpful and I know very very little about Kanji to dispute it, haha. I got confused especially since Google Translate displays the romanji of 保安官 as "sherifu" but it says ホアンカン upon clicking the "Listen" button. Is 保安官 genuinely pronounced as ホアンカン?

Comment: See [the entry at Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BF%9D%E5%AE%89%E5%AE%98).  It's all in Japanese, but you can see the kana rendering in the headline: 「ほ あんかん」.  See also [the English Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BF%9D%E5%AE%89%E5%AE%98), just a stub really, but it does show the reading.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, Google Translate does something especially weird and confusing in this case...

[image]

(And the voice synthesizer says "Jon Hoankan"! I wonder how they programmed this...)

If your character is like [this](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/James_Strickland) or [this](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Leigh_Johnson), their title is translated as 保安官, which is a kanji word pronounced ほあんかん or "hoankan". ほあんかん is the correct pronunciation, and that `sherifu` on the right of the picture is purely wrong. (I know nothing about the legal details, but 保安官 is a recurring title in fiction of the "wild west" settings.)

You can *transliterate* "sheriff" as シェリフ in katakana, but ordinary Japanese people do not understand its meaning at all.

Answer (score 3):

I'm really a beginner on japanese, but maybe this can be helpful:

Searching at [Jisho](http://jisho.org) (an amazing dictionary, if you don't know it yet) for "sheriff", I found the [same kanji](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BF%9D%E5%AE%89%E5%AE%98) that you got on Google Translate, with the same pronunciation (ほあんかん). Also, searching for this kanji on Google images, I found these two images:

[image]   [image]

It is from a manga called 保安官エヴァンスの嘘 or The Lies of Sheriff Evans. So, ほあんかん seems to really shows the meaning that you want.